# What is meant by numeric sequence?

Tags: python

The variable matrix contains 16 float values and I want to create an instance of `Matrix`

```
 m = Matrix( matrix[0:4],matrix[4:8],matrix[8:12],matrix[12:16] )
 qr = m.to_quaternion()
```

This leads to:

TypeError: Matrix(): expects no args or 2-4 numeric sequences

I tried to put parthesises around each expression like `(matrix[0:4])`
What is meant by numeric sequence when neither way works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mathutils.Matrix` behavior changed so that it expects a single argument, but the error message wasn't updated [(now done)](http://developer.blender.org/rB3e49787b01160b21a3b349c77c279eae5dccffb3)

This works as expected:

```
m = Matrix((matrix[0:4], matrix[4:8], matrix[8:12], matrix[12:16]))
qr = m.to_quaternion()
```

Mailing list thread as to [why the changes was made](http://markmail.org/message/xgxkrhvul5zlzs35)

Comment: Note the parenthesis around the argument -> numeric sequence in the form of a tuple (am I right ?) :P

Comment: it is, but a list will work as well.